# Approximate measurable function 3

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f$ be a measurable function on $E$ that is finite a.e. on $E$ and $m(E) < \infty$. For each $\epsilon > 0$, show that there is a measurable set $F$ contained in $E$ such that $f$ is bounded on $F$ and $m(E - F) < \epsilon.$

Any help?, Thanks

Comment: Actually there are two Problems, second one is based on the first problem:
Second Problem is:
2) Let $I$ be a closed, bounded interval and $E$ a measurable subset of $I$. Let $\epsilon > 0$. Show that there is a step function $h$ on $I$ and a measurable subset $F$ of $I$ for which
$$h = \aleph_E \text{ on F and } m(I - F) < \epsilon.$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

For every $n\in\mathbb N$ function $f$ is bounded on $F_n:=\{x\in E\mid |f(x|\leq n\}$.

What happens to $F_n$ (and $mF_n$) if $n$ grows?

---

**edit**:

$F_{n}\uparrow F:=\{x\in E|f(x)\text{ is finite}\}$ hence $mF_{n}\uparrow mF=mE$ because $f$ is finite a.e..

Combined with $mE<\infty$ this allows the conclusion that $m(E-F_n)=mE-mF_n\rightarrow 0$

Comment: I would say grows to E?, Any way you can show full prove? Thanks

Comment: See my edit. Good night.